# what is the difference in überlegen when it becomes transitive and intransitive?

Tags: verb

I came to realise that the verb überlegen can both be transitive and intransitive, which means that when I say I consider it can either be Ich überlege or Ich überlege mir. What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise isn't entirely correct. Rather than "ich überlege mich" you would have to say "ich überlege mir", i.e. use the dative *mir* (indirect object) rather than the accusative *mich* (direct object). This is because we are not dealing with a verb that can be intransitive or transitive, but with one that can be intransitive *(überlegen)* or transitive-reflexive *(sich etwas überlegen)*. Basically, if you want to use *überlegen* transitively in order to express *what* you are thinking, you would almost always make it reflexive as well - and without a direct object you can't make it reflexive.

If you consider that *etwas überlegen* (rarely used in this irreflexive transitive form) is essentially a synonym of *etwas denken* and that it is often best translated as *think [of] something*, everything should become clear:

- Ich überlege (mir) etwas. / Und ich überlege mir so: Was für eine wunderbare Welt!
- Ich denke (mir) etwas. / Und ich denke mir so: Was für eine wunderbare Welt!
- I think [of] something (to myself). / And I think to myself: What a wonderful world!

Making this verb reflexive is similar to adding a casualty marker. Thinking a thought just *to yourself* is more casual than thinking it publicly. Of course the nuances are subtle and the constructions in the two languages don't necessarily map to each other precisely:

- Ich hab mir überlegt/gedacht, wir könnten heute Abend ausgehen.
- I thought we might go out tonight.

As happens often, in German you have to make the casual nature explicit by using the reflexive form, making it clear that this is intended as a proposal rather than a (disappointed) statement of fact:

- Mist! Und ich dachte, wir könnten heute Abend ausgehen.
- Drat! And I thought we might go out tonight.

Comment: The question has been modified and your first sentence doesn't reflect that change.